# JAVASCRIPT How to create Multi-dimensional array in format for ajax post

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

I need help with this js code that needs to create a  Multi-dimensional js array in format which later to be sent via ajax.
From the table below I need to collect the following information for the selected services by each customer:
Client ID to be the key for the array which will hold another array with selected service_id, client_price, trener_bonus
Please mind that the services tables per player could be more than 1. For exapmple the client may order to training with 2 treners together so than for that player there will be a second table with services that the player can choose so thats why each player servies array must have subarray with a key trener_id which will hold the selected services per each trener..

[image]

My code is:

```
var treners_services_list= new Array();

$(".player_row").each(function(){
var player_id = $(this).attr('data-client');
if(!treners_services_list['p'+player_id]) treners_services_list['p'+player_id] = [];

$('#treners_services_table_'+player_id).find('.service_check_group:checked').each(function(){
var sid = $(this).val();
var trener_id = $(this).attr('data-trener');

if(!treners_services_list['p'+player_id]['t'+trener_id]){
treners_services_list['p'+player_id]['t'+trener_id] = [];
}

  treners_services_list['p'+player_id]['t'+trener_id].push({
    service_id: sid,
    client_price: $('#trener_client_price_'+sid).val(),
    trener_bonus: $('#trener_bonus_price_'+sid).val()

    });
    })

})
  console.log(treners_services_list);
```

I have prepared [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lvejad1h/1/) but the array which I am generating won't be sent via ajax.. I tried to convert it using this:

```
var myArray = $.makeArray(treners_services_list);
```

but still ajax doesn't accept it.

Can you please help me to generate the array in correct format but to hold the whole needed information above, Thanks

The js code in the fiddle generates this array which is not being accepted by ajax.. I tried to convert it with JSON.stringify() but that it becomes empty:
[image]

Comment: JSON.stringify()

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was setting on the top:

```
if(!treners_services_list['p'+player_id]) treners_services_list['p'+player_id] = [];
```

instead of:

```
if(!treners_services_list['p'+player_id]) treners_services_list['p'+player_id] = {};
```

Thanks for your help !